# how to manage knockout select option groups?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to render my categories in `optgroups` and dynamically changing `itemsCount` in brands.

When I change `itemsCount` 0 to positive value dynamically, the selected option also changes (only UI change, not observable change).

```
<select class="form-control brand-selector pull-left" 
        data-bind="value: $data.selectedBrand">
    <!-- ko if:$data.popularBrands().length -->
    <optgroup label="popular brands" data-bind="foreach:$data.brands">
        <!-- ko if: $data.itemsCount -->
        <option data-bind="text: $data.Caption, option: $data"></option>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </optgroup>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if:$data.possibleBrands().length-->
    <optgroup label="All possible families" data-bind="foreach:$data.brands">
        <!-- ko ifnot:$data.itemssCount -->
        <option data-bind="text: $data.Caption, option: $data"></option>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </optgroup>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

How can I prevent selected option change?

Comment: Can you include the your vm, or atleast the part of it that applies to the html above

Comment: Have you tried valueAllowUnset?